# After closing the screen, android closes socket connection in few minutes

Tags: android, socket.io, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat, socket.io-java-client

I am implementing a real time taxi-hailing application with socket-io and in the implementation of driver application, we are dealing with socket problem. Even if the user closes the device screen, i just want to keep socket connection alive. Is there any specific permission for android?

Is there any suggestions about keeping the socket alive?

Sharing my permission lists.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

And my socket connection and socket handling codes are below. 
For connection:

```
    public Observable<SocketConnection.State> connect(String customerId) {
    if (mUserId == null || mUserType == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (mAddress == null) {
        mAddress = Constants.DEFAULT_SOCKET_ADDRESS;
    }
    mNamespace = Constants.DEFAULT_SOCKET_NAMESPACE;
    if (customerId != null) {
        mNamespace = Constants.CUSTOMER_SOCKET_NAMESPACE;
    }
    if (socket != null) {
        socket.disconnect();
        removeSocketListeners();
    }

    try {
        socket = IO.socket(mAddress + mNamespace, getOptions(customerId));
        setSocketListeners();
        startInternalPong();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socket.connect();
    return mConnectionObservable;
}
```

For disconnect:

```
public Observable<SocketConnection.State> disconnect() {

    if (socket != null) {
        removeSocketListeners();
        socket.disconnect();
    }
    return mConnectionObservable;
}
```

Connection Observer:

```
    private Observable<SocketConnection.State> mConnectionObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<SocketConnection.State>() {

    @Override
    public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<SocketConnection.State> observableEmitter) throws Exception {
        mConnectionObservableEmitter = observableEmitter;

        observableEmitter.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
            @Override
            public void cancel() throws Exception {
                mConnectionObservableEmitter = null;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: can you post code regarding socket handling?

Comment: Keeping connection alive while app is not in foreground is a very bad practice. There must be another way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Android Bacgrkound Services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Also refer to these answers:

- [how to run a socket in a long lives background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32248117/2734302)
- [Android socket connect in background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223751/2734302)